# Laravel foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed (errno 150)

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

can someone tell me why do I get a foreign key is incorrectly formed?

Here is part of the code:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->string('featured');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
```

Here is the categories table:

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
```

**Note**

It does not drop this error for 'user_id' foreign key just for categories.

**FIX FOR THIS ISSUE**

just change date on your database/migrations - migration for example if you want your categories to be created before posts table do this change:

2020_08_06_172006_create_posts_table.php
2020_08_09_172006_create_categories_table.php

change date on categories migration from
**2020_08_09** to for example **2020_*07*_09**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your table `posts` is created before `categories`
Therefore, you cannot constraint `posts.category_id` to the `categories.id` table.

In order to fix the issue you should create the table `categories` before creating the table `posts`

Comment: So, is there a way to tell laravel which order I want? Btw. I guess you are right, I've just checked migration and there is not categories table created before posts table.

Comment: The only way I know to order the migrations is by changing the date in the filename. Make sure to run `composer dump` to re-reference the files

Comment: Thank you so much. This was so easy to fix.